# Find h so that the matrix can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, parametric, diagonalization

I have to find the $h$ parameter of the matrix so that it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix.

\begin{pmatrix}
h & h+1 & 0 \\
2h & 1 & h-1 \\
2h-2 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

The solution provided for this problem is that the given matrix, since it has to be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix, must be symmetric, hence $h=1$.

The matrix that diagonalises another matrix, named $U$, is the one that has $A$'s Eigenvectors in column, so that

$D = U^{-1} AU$

and $D$ is the matrix with $A$'s Eigenvalues as its trace.

I find this incorrect but I'm not sure. I've done a lot of exercises like this and in 80% of the cases the matrix that diagonalized the matrix was orthogonal without the main matrix being symmetric.

Is it correct to assume that the matrix must be symmetric to be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix or the solution is just **partially** correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D = U^{-1} A U$ is a diagonal matrix, then 
$A = U D U^{-1} = U D U^T$ is symmetric.

Comment: And symmetric matrices are the **only** ones that can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix then?

Comment: That's what I meant by "Yes".

Comment: Ok, good to know. One last thing, to find that orthogonal matrix I need to find all the eigenvectors, normalize them and then put them by columns in the matrix right?